# How to read ".opf" and ".ncx" files in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, cpan

I want to read "`.opf`" and "`.ncx`" files using Perl

Kindly suggest any idea to do this

Thanks

Vimal

Answer (score 0):

You should use [EPUB parser](http://search.cpan.org/~tokubass/EPUB-Parser-0.05/lib/EPUB/Parser/File/OPF.pm) module available from CPAN.

Usage

```
 use EPUB::Parser;
 my $ep = EPUB::Parser->new->load_file({ file_path  => 'sample.epub' });
 my $opf = $ep->opf;
```

Comment: I want to access OPF file directly without mapping .epub file, pls suggest any way if you know, but thank you so much for your swift reply

Comment: From what I know OPF is in XML format. So you can even use XML parser if you want to read it directly